# How to read and store UHF tag UID using python and zebra

Tags: python, python-2.7, rfid, zebra-printers, zpl

I have a zebra R110Xi4 printer and i am struggling to pull the tag UID and encode it to the EPC,using just ZPL to do it is not possible so i was thinking to use python to do it in 2 steps (read and encode) so far i found several ways to use python to send ZPL and EPL command to it but not how to get information back from the printer .

I wanted to know how can i read and store the UID of the tag using the Zebra module(or any other way) and not just encode and print it.

In simpale words i want to read the UID of the tag, do some manipulation to it and write it back to the EPC.

Zebra python module:
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/zebra/

There is another option to [use TCP/IP to send ZPL to the printer](https://gist.github.com/gourneau/8e19234b00a879d66671) but i know that i cant get information back from the printer using TCP/IP

Br,
Idan

Comment: I'd skip the Zebra Python module as it looks like it outputs EPL, and I'm not sure EPL provides the necessary commands to write RFID tags.  You can get a response back over TCP/IP though.  Take a look at this example in C# https://km.zebra.com/kb/index?page=content&id=SA140&actp=RSS

Answer (score 0):

To get the TID and encode into the EPC, I've done this, which stores the encoding command then backfeeds to the correct tag and print/encode the TID onto the EPC. I used the Zebra RZ400 and the tag itself is EPC Class 1 Gen2 and has a 96-bit TID. It may differ depending on what tags you have.

```
^XA
^DFR:TEST.ZPL
^PRA,A
^FO40,40^A0N,40,40^FN1^FS
^RS8,B20^RFW,H^FN1^FS
^XZ
^XA
^XFR:TEST.ZPL
^FN1^RFR,H,0,12,2^FS
^MD30
^XZ
```